# Can I monitor problems in the TCP/IP stack from C#

Tags: c#, tcp

We run a number of services, which expose data on https listeners
Lately we have seen issues which might be related to problems with low-level TCP/IP packets

Could be a client is not responding timely with ACK to our network packets
Or filling up our TCP/IP stack by sending us requests and only receiving the response very slowly
Or maybe even lost network packets and retransmit

Is it possible to monitor and capture problems with TCP/IP messages in a C# service?

Comment: I would suggest using a packet analyzer like wireshark. That should let you capture all packets on the machine, and filter by port or application. But this is probably a question for https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Yes. Wireshark could be a tool to use outside of our application. I was hoping it could be part of our applications so we can generate alarms to our DevOps when such a problem occurs. However I have no idea how to capture the information in a C# application

Comment: As far as I know, you can't. An application operate on the [*application layer*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model#Layer_7:_Application_layer). If you need information from the *transport layer* you need to write your own network filter driver (or whatever it is called). But the problem is unlikely to be in the TCP-stack. Either you have some messed up network config, or perhaps more likely, your software is buggy. Stephen Clearys [TCP/IP FAQ](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/tcpip-net-sockets-faq.html) might be useful.